# Gold Standard data for training but not validation

Tags: cross-validation, validation, sensitivity-specificity

My goal is to determine which among the three classification algorithms perform better `{ Logist Reg or Neural Network or SVM }`.

I have a training dataset and the outcome variable y has been manually verified to determine which is true which not true. So I have a gold standard for this dataset.

I have a validation dataset  where the y has not been manually verified to determine which is true and which is not, so I dont have gold standard data for this validation dataset.

How do compare the performance of these three algorithms under such conditions where I have gold standard for training data and not for validation data. Any pointers or suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: I don't really follow your situation. Can you say more? What are your data? What do you mean by "verified"? What are the goals of your study?

Comment: @gung, I am comparing the performances of three different classification algorithms. I have gold standard data for the training dataset but not for the validation dataset. My question is how do i compare the performance of these three algorithms under such situation.

Answer (score 1):

Not getting reference values for the "test" set is IMHO a total waste of the data collection and training effort. It is often possible to train a model on data where only part of the training cases have reference values/labels (semi-supervised models), but testing really requires reference values/labels.

---

While you can measure *some* characteristics of model performance without reference (e.g. stability of predictions wrt. changes in training set) for the prediction, they alone are not sufficient to demonstate good predictive quality of the model.
There are situations where they demonstrate that the model in question is too bad to be of any use, though.